# How to validate a potential database name?

Tags: mysql, odbc

I want to prompt the user to enter a database name and warn him if it is invalid.

Is there an easier way than actually trying to create the database and checking the result?

No biggy, I'm just curious.  PHP and MySql, but I need it to be ODBC compliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have your PHP script validate the name before submitting it, *and* have it catch any error that comes back from MySQL when trying to create it.

The PHP could validate the name against a regular expression, for example. Maybe you want to only permit alphabetical characters.

In fact, I strongly recommend *only* accepting alphabetical characters, and validating this before ever sending anything to a database command... no sense giving anyone any chance to submit values that could end up causing SQL injection, in the context of a user with the ability to create databases.

But I would also ask; Do you really need to allow users to define their own database names? It might seem 'nice' to enable it, but is there any real benefit over generating a semi-random or incrementing name to users, eliminating any need to validate their input in this particular case?

Comment: +1 Know you of such a regular expression?  And is that more certain than trying to create and checking the result?  I just wondered how others do this, it must be fairly standard.

Comment: Oh, sorry; meant to post that, too: `^[a-zA-Z]{10,20}$` would only match a name using only letters, that is from 10-20 characters long. You could probably add the underscore in there safely too, and numbers; but I wouldn't add any more than that.

Comment: +1 Thanks, but I am beginning to think that it might just be best to try to create the database & see if it succeeds. AS @ajreal points out, the name may be valid, but the user may not have the access rights to create it.